# R stars::st_as_sf( , merge = TRUE) not working properly with Raster - Points with same values are not all merged

Tags: r, r-sf, r-raster, r-stars

I have been trying to polygonize a raster in R and ran into memory issues. Searching for solutions, I found this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192771/how-to-speed-up-raster-to-polygon-conversion-in-r) with a routine using the `stars` [package](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/) in R that I felt could solve my issues. I provide a reproducible example below that should be fast to run (I need to polygonize a raster that is actually much larger than this one).

Basically, my issue is that I have a raster in which all gridpoints have the same values. I want to polygonize it to a single multipolygon (like what I would get with `rasterToPolygons(data, dissolve = TRUE)`). To do so, I tried converting my raster to a star object (`stars::st_as_stars(data)`) and then convert to a sf object with the option for merging cells with the same value (`st_as_sf(data, merge = TRUE)`). The option `merge = TRUE` is available through the stars package, not the sf one, more details are available [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stars/versions/0.5-6/topics/st_as_sf). This is merging some cells, but not all of them and I don't know why. I also don't know what to do to fix this issue.

```
library(CropScapeR)
library(httr)
library(stars)
library(raster)
library(sf)

   #THIS IS JUST TO GET THE DATA I AM WORKING WITH, THE CROPLAND DATA LAYER BY USDA
   #To download CDL data on Linux using CropscapeR i need to do the below process as per
   #the instructions in the package page (in Windows you can basically go directly to)
   #GetCDLData(.) part
   # Skip the SSL check
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
   # Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')
ST_CDL1 <- GetCDLData(aoi = '34001', year = 2021, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file)
writeRaster(ST_CDL1, "ST_CDL1.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
ST_CDL1 = raster("ST_CDL1.tif")

   #NOW IS WHERE MY QUESTION ACTUALLY BEGINS
   #I create a new raster only with the cells in which I have blueberries.
   #In this raster all cells should have the same value: 242
ST_CDL_blueberries1 <- 
  raster::reclassify(ST_CDL1,
                     c(-0.1,241.9,NA,
                       242.1,255.1,NA),
                     progress="text")

   #My idea here is to convert the raster to a star object and then use
   #st_as_sf( , merge = TRUE) to get an sf object with a multipolygon for all
   #all blueberry fields. As mentioned above, people claimed elsewhere that this
   #is much faster than doing what I was trying before (more details on that below)
ST_CDL_blueberries1 <- stars::st_as_stars(ST_CDL_blueberries1)
   #This code should not merge the blueberry fields, it yields 52260 observations
   #Notice I run sf::st_as_sf, not stars::st_as_sf, even though as I said above I am
   #the merge option which comes from the stars package. However, for some reason when
   #I try to run stars::st_as_sf the code does not work.
ST_CDL_blueberries1false <- sf::st_as_sf(ST_CDL_blueberries1, 
             as_points = FALSE, merge = FALSE)
   #This code should merge the blueberry fields, it yields 5908 observations, which
   #is less than before, but I was hoping to really get a single observation
ST_CDL_blueberries1true <- sf::st_as_sf(ST_CDL_blueberries1, 
             as_points = FALSE, merge = TRUE)
```

If you want an example of something that actually works, but that was crashing due to excessive ram requirements when I tried to run it in a larger raster, here it is:

```
#Starting from the reclassify step in the above code

ST_CDL_blueberries1 <- 
  raster::reclassify(ST_CDL,
                     c(-0.1,241.9,NA,
                       242.1,255.1,NA),
                     progress="text")


#Poligonyzing the rasters and then making them sf objects
ST_CDL_blueberries1 <- rasterToPolygons(ST_CDL_blueberries1, dissolve = TRUE)
ST_CDL_blueberries1 <- st_as_sf(ST_CDL_blueberries1)
```

My specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
- RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (e7373ef832b49b2a9b88162cfe7eac5f22c40b34, 2022-09-06) for Ubuntu Jammy Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
- CropScapeR 1.1.4
- httr 1.4.4
- raster 3.6-3
- sf 1.0-8
- stars 0.5-6

Thanks for your help! :)

As said in comments in the code, I have compared the results under `st_as_sf(data, merge = TRUE)` and `st_as_sf(data, merge = FALSE)`. When `merge = TRUE` I indeed get less observations, but since I know my dataset has the same values for all cells, I should be getting only one observation, that's where my issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. But instead of `raster::rasterAsPolygons`, you could the more efficient `terra::as.polygons` ("terra" has replaced "raster"). Here is a simple example

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f) |> classify(5)
p <- as.polygons(r)

plot(p, "elevation")
```

As you can see, the default setting is to dissolve all cells that have the same value into a single multi-polygon.

But you probably should not do this at all. Representing raster data as polygons generally is a *terrible* idea. Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: Robert, Why is representing  raster data as polygons a bad idea? My main goal is to intersect buffers around blueberry fields with forests and calculate the area of these buffers that contain forests. If I do so for all buffers I can plot a histogram of the areas intersection. I decided to polygonize the rasters because I want to  intersect the buffers to a single polygon with all forests at once (and I can do that with st_intersection). My understanding is that if I were to use raster::intersect, I would get an intersection for each frid point with forests.

Comment: Because the memory needs for polygons are much larger (polygons: 5 coordinate pairs for *each grid cell* (but fewer if cells get merged); raster: 4 coordinate pairs for the *entire dataset*. So you are asking for memory trouble. Processing can also be much more efficient for raster data because the geometry is known to be regular. You can use raster-based methods to find out how much forest there is around blueberry fields (but not with `intersect`). You could ask a question about that with some simple example data.